# How to implement Add products option in ui form Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, admin, ui

I have a product block like(refer image) and  I  loaded the productgrid using( https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/)and successfully saved.After when I try to edit the block (I Want to add more products to grid) I have only seen the products that I added early only. How to add new products to the grid?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For adding the button through UI form, you need to do following steps

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/custom_created_form.xml

You need to add data with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="button-unique-identifier-here" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Then create the class

> [Namespace][Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton
> in the file
> [Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/CustomButton.php

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class CustomButton extends Generic
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Add Product'),
            'on_click' => "alert('it works..')",
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
}
```

Please upvote the answer if helpful

Comment: Actually I have loaded the productgrid using( https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/ )and successfully saved.After when I try to edit the block (I Want to add more products to grid) I have only seen the products that I added early only. How to add new products to the grid?????